# (F#) Inbuilt function to filter a list if it does not contain a specific value

Tags: f#, functional-programming

My question is regarding list filtering in F#. Is there a built in function that allows the filtering of lists where it only returns those that do not satisfy a condition?

```
let listOfList = [ [1;2;3;4;5]; [6;7;8;9;10]; [11;2;5;14;1] ]
let neededValue = 1
```

I know that F# features List.Contains() however I want to only return lists which do not satisfy the condition.

```
let sortedLists = listOfList |> List.filter(fun x -> x <> x.Contains(neededValue)
```

This obviously does not work because in this instance I'm comparing a list to whether a list contains a specific value. How would I do this? My desired output in this instance would be:

```
sortedLists = [ [6;7;8;9;10] ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were so close! Change `x <>` to `not <|`, and it will work.

```
let listOfList = [ [1;2;3;4;5]; [6;7;8;9;10]; [11;2;5;14;1] ]
let neededValue = 1

let sortedLists = listOfList |> List.filter(fun x -> not <| x.Contains(neededValue))
```

The `not` function allows you to negate a boolean value, so that the types in the filter expression match up.

Comment: Many thanks, I can't believe something that simple was throwing me.

Answer (score 1):

In f# it's more idiomatic to use

```
List.contains neededValue x
```

instead of

```
 x.Contains(neededValue)
```

So I would express it like this

```
let sortedLists =
    listOfList 
    |> List.filter (List.contains neededValue >> not)
```